# PHP Contact Form not working - It downloads instead if executing

Tags: php, contact-form

Good day! Uh, I have a PHP contact form here. The codes were correct since I checked online and my codes were almost the same as the ones on the internet. I even tried the ones on the internet. But whenever I try to execute them, they never work! >3< instead of showing the whole webpage, the webpage itself is being downloaded into a PHP file. The webpage never showed unless I change the file format into HTML. But the PHP codes won't work then. WAH! Please, help me! Btw, I haven't uploaded it on the website yet. ^^

Any kind of help would be very much appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: post a bit of code, then you have more change people helping you out.

Comment: Yes without any code you're unlikely to get much help.

Comment: Is this online or are you running it locally on your machine? php is a server side language so wont work locally just in your browser. If you want to get it working locally use some thing like MAMP

Answer (score 0):

I think your apache doesn't execute PHP files. You have to check wether your PHP configuration is working.

http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-php-5-apache-windows.shtml

You have to check couple of things.

1. Check whether your PHP installation is correct. (The installation is depending on your OS)
2. Check whether you have configured PHP with your web server (Configuration depends on the web server)